# Reusing a pointer after `delete`

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is it safe and/or good practice to do something as the following?

```
//NewList is a member function of a class
void NewList(int size){

delete[] list; //list is a member variable; an already initialized dynamic array.

list=new ListObject[size];

}
```

I'm basically discarding the previous array because I will use different data to store in the class, and hence require a new `list` to store other information on the new data. If this is not good practice, what's the alternative?

Comment: Did you read the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)? It's legal to assign a pointer to new memory, whether or not it's **safe** depends on the rest of the code.

Comment: "Is it safe and/or good practice to do something as the following?" Yes, it is safe. Whether it is good is subject to opinions.

Comment: What you are doing is perfectly acceptable if you **need** to use an array (unlikely). Otherwise use a `std::vector`

Comment: Okay, I just wasn't sure if `delete` was going to invalidate the pointer, so when I want to reuse it, I thought maybe I should keep a list of allocated memory addresses and only use `delete` on the whole list before the end of the program. I'll read the link "Rule of Three" in a few moments.

Comment: Yes, `delete` invalidates the pointer, meaning that dereferencing that pointer causes undefined behavior. That doesn't mean you can't reuse the pointer to store a new address though.

Comment: @user25164 - after calling `delete []`, `list` is a dangling pointer. e.g., its value is meaningless, and dereferencing the pointer is [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If the subsequent `new []` fails, the default new handler throws `std::bad_alloc`, without changing the value of `list`.

Comment: I hate stupid answers like "use a vector".  That wasn't your question.  Yes, it's perfectly safe and perfectly appropriate to assign a new object to a variable you've already "deleted".

Comment: @FoggyDay Because saying "it's safe" answers the title of the question, but fails to address the big picture. What the OP doing probably isn't safe, even though you can reassign pointers perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. Every time you create an object with new, you must delete it after use. In the given function you are deleting to create a new one, but are you also deleting once you are done with the object? It's safer to create your object and have the system delete it when the object is out of scope.

I would avoid if possible as you can create a memory leak if not deleted appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's totally fine to reuse a pointer to store a new memory address after deleting the previous memory it pointed to.

Just be careful not to dereference the old memory address which is still stored in the pointer. In your code snippet that's not a problem though.

As a side note, most of the time, you should use `std::vector` if you want a dynamically-allocated array, as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with what you're doing.  However, if it is a member function of a class, and `list` is a member variable, be aware that the code you have is *not* exception safe.

In other words, if the call to `new[]` fails for some reason, your `list` array has been destroyed, and you can't recover the data.

Better to do this:

```
void NewList(int size)
{
    ListObject* temp = new ListObject[size]; 
    delete[] list; 
    list = temp;
}
```

If the call to `new[]` throws an exception, you haven't destroyed your original data.

However, all of this is taken care of if you used `std::vector`, as others have suggested.