# using reference pointer type as Paramter in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I faced some problem when i use Reference pointer type as parameter.

first, this is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(int*& ptr);

int main(void)
{
int* ptr = new int[1];
ptr[0] = 100;
cout << ptr[0];

test(ptr);
cout << ptr[0] << '\t' << ptr[1];
}

void test(int*& ptr)
{
int* tmp = new int[2];
tmp[0] = 1;
tmp[1] = 2;

int* tmp2 = ptr;
ptr = tmp;
cout << ptr[0] << '\t' << ptr[1];
delete[]tmp2;
}
```

and when compiled this code, the output is

```
100
1       2
```

this output is what i want to get

but when i debug this code,

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
```

this error has occurred.

how to avoid this error, and what is my fault? :(

and what should i do when reallcoate parameter's memory without using reference type?

Comment: Reference types aren't the problem; fundamental and basic understand of dynamic memory management and pointers *is*. Ex: `delete[]ptr;` destroys the memory you just allocated. Back in `main` you now have a dangling pointer. You're also leaking the original memory allocated in `main`. Unrelated, `tmp2` is worthless, and arguably so is `tmp`.

Comment: single item in passed ptr and accessing ptr[1] means second item

Comment: oh, sorry guys i fixed my code...

Comment: what i want to know is when i call a function that have parameter(memory allocated pointer(reference type)), can i change the address that paramter(pointer) point in function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference isn't the problem. It's your dynamic memory management that is dreadfully broken.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(int *&ptr);

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = new int[1]; // allocates a sequence of 1
    ptr[0] = 100;
    cout << ptr[0];

    test(ptr); // sends pointer to sequence by reference to test
    cout << ptr[0] << '\t' << ptr[1];
}

void test(int *&ptr)
{
    int *tmp = new int[2]; // allocates a sequence of size 2
    tmp[0] = 1;
    tmp[1] = 2;

    int *tmp2 = ptr; // stores original passed-in pointer to tmp2
    ptr = tmp; // assigns new sequence pointer to reference argument (leaks original)
    cout << ptr[0] << '\t' << ptr[1];

    delete[] ptr; // deletes the new sequence. (leaves dangling pointer)
}
```

What you seem to be *trying* to do is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(int *&ptr);

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = new int[1];
    ptr[0] = 100;
    cout << ptr[0] << '\n';

    test(ptr);
    cout << ptr[0] << '\t' << ptr[1] << '\n';
    delete [] ptr;
}

void test(int *&ptr)
{
    delete [] ptr;    // delete original sequence
    ptr = new int[2]; // create new sequence
    ptr[0] = 1;
    ptr[1] = 2;
}
```

---

**Stop Using Raw Pointers**

Alternatively, use smart pointers to manage this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

void test(std::unique_ptr<int[]>& ptr);

int main(void)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(1);
    ptr[0] = 100;
    cout << ptr[0] << '\n';

    test(ptr);
    cout << ptr[0] << '\t' << ptr[1] << '\n';
}

void test(std::unique_ptr<int[]>& ptr)
{
    ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);
    ptr[0] = 1;
    ptr[1] = 2;
}
```

Or better still, just use a `std::vector<int>`

Comment: thanks for answer, 
but , can i use pointer again that had deleted?

Comment: what happened in memory when i delete memory allocation?
is  deleted pointer pointing NULL or garbage value?

Comment: [What is a dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer).

Comment: than, can i use deleted pointer whenever i want with being sure avoid dangling pointer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379457/reusing-a-pointer-after-delete/28379518
oh, i found my question's answer! 
thank you!